# Are there any practically proposed/implemented ways to treat charities differently?

Tags: taxes

Many countries allow people to write off philanthropic donations off of their taxes.

In the USA, there doesn't seem to be ANY difference in this policy based on philanthropic purpose - you can write off both the donations to institutions that have at least a semblance of an argument that support for them is in the interest of the country (e.g. help to the poor; or medical research); AND donations to institutions that don't seem to have ANY legitimate argument that support for them is in the direct interest of the country, worth losing the tax revenue (e.g. support for fine arts).

Are there any practically proposed/implemented ways to treat charities differently as far as taxation based on the purpose of the charity? This doesn't have to be in USA (though I'm particularly interested in US-specific answers), but has to be something that is an official proposal - e.g., a large organization with tons of members pushing it, or an officially proposed law even if it didn't pass.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd even begin to determine "practicality", which I'm sure is a big part of the reason that this is not in place now in the US.  You are for medical research but against art, but what about a charity that provides artwork to children in long-term care?  How would you draw the line?

Comment: I think the fact that you don't believe there are legitimate arguments for public arts spending seems to answer the question: There's no practical way to treat charities differently because everyone will have a different concept of what is legitimate.

Comment: @JNK - that's still "art", unless there's a legitimate medical study going on with the goal of improving medical outcomes via artwork. The line is very simple: you allow stuff which either directly helps someone satisfy lower levels of Maslow's hierarchy of needs (house: yes. Paintings: no). OR is research with potentially good payoff, economic or life quality wise (mostly, fundamental research).

Comment: @DA. - Legitimate argument != should add to the budget. It's fine to spend on arts when you have major surplus. When your family is facing bankruptcy, you pay rent and food bills, NOT buy paintings and go to concerts (well, if you're one of those idiot losers who still think that people should be responsible for themselves).

Comment: @DVK  can you imagine someone deeming something like the ACLU a non-legitimate charity?

Comment: @SamIam - I'm agnostic on whether political non-for-profits are valid tax writeoffs, but I'd lean towards excluding them. There's no pressing government need to be subsidizing any of them - they are wallowing in money as it is these days, on any political side.

Comment: Yes the Left would like to make all right wing charities no longer exempt.  The right would like to make all left wing charities no longer exempt.  And I would like to make the money they pay their executives no longer exempt.

Comment: @SamIam, FTR, as a regular contributor to the ACLU, I can state with certainty that the ACLU is not a charity, and all contributions to them are in fact taxable.  They are a registered not-for-profit organization, not a charity.

Answer (score 4):

Arguably, this already occurs.

In the UK, the Charities Act 2006 [defines a charity](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/50/section/1) as being *"established for charitable purposes only"*; a [charitable purpose being further defined](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/50/section/2) as being *"for the public benefit"* within a fairly narrow set of criteria:

> (a)  the prevention or relief of poverty;
>   (b)  the advancement of education;
>   (c)  the advancement of religion;
>   (d)  the advancement of health or the saving of lives;
>   (e)  the advancement of citizenship or community development;
>   (f)  the advancement of the arts, culture, heritage or science;
>   (g)  the advancement of amateur sport;
>   (h)  the advancement of human rights, conflict resolution or reconciliation or the promotion of religious or racial harmony or equality and diversity;
>   (i)  the advancement of environmental protection or improvement;
>   (j)  the relief of those in need by reason of youth, age, ill-health, disability, financial hardship or other disadvantage;
>   (k)  the advancement of animal welfare;
>   (l)  the promotion of the efficiency of the armed forces of the Crown, or of the efficiency of the police, fire and rescue services or ambulance services;
>   (m)  any other purposes within subsection (4).

The Charity Commission has [a (fairly large) pdf](http://www.charitycommission.gov.uk/Library/guidance/lawpb1208.pdf), which interprets this act and the surrounding case law in order to offer guidance.

As a donor, [no gifts to charity](https://www.gov.uk/donating-to-charity/different-ways-to-donate) are, technically, tax free. Depending on how you give, the donor can either grant the charity permission to claim back paid tax or have [HMRC automatically work out the real value of the gift before tax](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/individuals/giving/basics.htm).

The main difference is a definitional argument - your question assumes a certain definition of "public good", which the UK government disagrees with. If an organisation were not to be benefiting the public then they would not be a charity. There is, therefore, no need for differing tax exemptions.

Comment: That *is* arguable... doesn't this just define "charity"?  There is no differentiation between charities; as long as an organization can be considered a charity, the same rules apply.

Comment: My contention @Jeremy is that the OPs definition of "public good" and "charity" is inconsistent with that of other people's. The differentiation between those deserving of tax-exempt status and those not has already taken place; it is the definition of a charity.

Comment: perhaps it's an interpretation issue with the OP, but it seems to me that the question is how to treat charities differently, not what defines a charity.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - more of treating the **donors** to charities differently. You may define it as "what's a charity" or not, that's more of semantics than policy.

Comment: @DVK, I cannot see how "treat charities differently as far as taxation based on the purpose of the charity" is donor-specific... it clearly seems to be charity-centric.  In that light, defining what is a charity and what is not a charity seems to be out of scope for the question asked.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - Currently, you get a tax write-off if you donate to non-profit to feed hungry children - the SAME tax write off as if you donate to an art museum. It's not written anywhere that the latter HAS to be tax-writeoffable.

Comment: @DVK, well that's precisely my point.  Currently, all charities are treated exactly the same.  The OP is asking how treating them differently could be practically implemented... defining/ redefining what constitutes a charity does not accomplish this.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - just to be clear, charity!=nonprofit. Charity is defined by Merriam-webster as an institution designed for relief of the poor. Non-profit (which is what the tax code is about) can be for ANY purpose conceivable except politics, as long as IRS certifies them as such.

Comment: @DVK, regardless of this distinction, OP is asking how to differentiate treatment of charities based on the purpose of the charity.  Whether it is or is not a charity does not address the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8451/discussion-between-jeremy-holovacs-and-dvk)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, DVK is the OP. He is asking whether there are any proposed ways to separate out different types of charities in the tax-code based on whether they serve the public good. I have answered that this has already happened. It is the definition of a charity; a way of separating out certain organisations based on whether they serve the public good. The _only_ difference is the OPs definition of public good and the UK government's.

Comment: @Ben, I agree that the only difference is the definition, and I am aware that DVK is the OP author, but stating the definition of charity or altering the definition of charity will not differentiate between charities like OP asks.  It may be that DVK's question and expected answer do not match each other, but in that case the question should change.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no", and for good reason.  I'm sure you could find an example of some charity in some country where they do differentiate, but the qualifier of "practical" turns this question in a specific direction.

Keep in mind there are two ways taxes are affected regarding charities: the donor, and of course, the charity itself.

To prioritize as you are suggesting, the way the organization helps must be firmly categorized into one legally defined group.  Many charities support multiple activities focused on helping people with needs.  Do you report Red Cross as a financial aid organization, a soup kitchen, an emergency medical organization?  It's all of these and more, and ignoring one over another serves no effective purpose... the organization would naturally be categorized as whatever it could qualify for with the most benefit to it.

Prioritization of the organization types would also be very difficult to get public consensus on.  Charity falls into several groups, like improving the average human condition (such as a volunteer medical research group), protecting and nurturing the helpless, easing the pain of the suffering, educating and empowering the hopeless, et cetera.  Each of these has importance on its own, and they are part of a whole.  Prioritizing one "type" of charity over another diminishes them (and us) all.

All of this being said, prioritization could theoretically be based off *performance*, assuming accurate metrics could be maintained.  You could get a break on your taxes for donating to charity "X" because they got a 5-star rating from the government... but this too is a conflict of interests.  This shifts the focus of a charity away from the helping of their fellow humans and more towards getting the most bang for the buck.  A few years of that sort of law and all charities (most of them at least) would end up focusing on the dollars.  "If we don't feed 100 homeless people every day, we'll lose our tax exemption status!  Go out and find homeless people, even if they live in your house with you!"

Next we could talk about all the paperwork, administration, and bureaucracy that would be inherent in making, maintaining, and auditing these "rules" for how a charity is to be evaluated.... a lot of paper for both the charity and the government.

Isn't it more practical, in every case, to put a blanket exemption down for all charities?  While the potential for abuse and corruption certainly exists, it is not significantly more than would occur if it were more regulated.

As an aside, I do not report my charitable donations to the IRS, as I feel it cheapens the donation, like I donated to get something out of it.  Unfortunately, if charitable donations were not tax-deductible, I fear we would lose quite a bit of charities in America, and I feel that is undesirable.

Comment: Didn't read the whole answer yet, but I was very specifically interested in taxes on the donor, NOT on the charity. Sorry for confusion.